# Align 3 inputs in the same row with label above

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a small issue here with aligning three input fields in the same row with equal space between each other.

I tried to do it with `display: flex` and space-between but then the label is placed left to the input and not on-top.

What I want to achieve is as followed:
[image: Example]

Then if there is more inputs I want it to "break a row" and start a new 3 input row.

How can I achieve it ?

Code snippet:

```css
/*Stage 3 input group*/
.dInput{
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.dInput label {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #f8f9fa;
}

.dInput input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: #495057;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dInput" v-if="activeStage == 3">
  <label for="name">Username*</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <label for="name">Username*</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
</div>
```

Comment: already tried grid?

Comment: I tried with 'grid-row' : auto , probably I used it in the wrong place

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the input and label in a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I hope my code is helpful to you.

```css
/*Stage 3 input group*/
.dInput{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.dInput label {
  text-align:center;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #000;
}

.dInput input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: #495057;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dInput" v-if="activeStage == 3">
  <div><label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"></div>
  <div><label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"></div>
  <div><label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"></div>
  
</div>
<div class="dInput" v-if="activeStage == 3">
  <div><label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"></div>
  <div><label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"></div>
  <div><label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: That's pretty good but as I mentioned in the question, I need it to be limited to 3 input fields in a row, so if there is 4 input fields a new row will start, is that possible?

Comment: @Profit23 you can use same HTML to achieve that  or you can fix the width of  div and use javascript.

Comment: Well it's on vuejs so I'll try. even though I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

`display: flex` implementation

```css
.dInput {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.input-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 33%;
  flex: 33%;
}

.dInput label {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
  /* color: #f8f9fa; */
}

.dInput input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: #495057;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dInput">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With css grid :

```css
/*Stage 3 input group*/
.dInput{
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  justify-items: center;
  background-color: violet;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.dInput label {
  display: block;
  color: #f8f9fa;
}

.dInput input {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #495057;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 8em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.dInput-item {
  justify-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dInput" v-if="activeStage == 3">
  <div class="dInput-item">
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="dInput-item">
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="dInput-item">
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="dInput-item">
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each label and input in a div

```
<div class="dInput">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Username*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.dInput{
  margin-top: 15px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: That seems to partially work, If there are more then 3 inputs I need it to break a row and create a new row with X other inputs